# SSH script to make a file in a folder inaccessible if it is opened previously and make it readable when closed

Tags: server, ssh, incron

I have files in a folder and I am accessing those files via sshfs through remote locations. I just want to know if there is a way to make the files accessible by only a single user i.e if some one else has opened a file previously it should not be accessible by others(May be by changing its permissions) and when the user releases(closes) the file others can access it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the file should be completely inaccessible, or just read-only when in use? It sounds like the concept you're searching for is called "file locking" but the typical behavior is to make it read-only when in use.

Comment: I want it to become completely inaccessible to others but not to the user who opened it.